# Android Studio, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.wilmar.rentacube.DAO.UserDao.getUserForSession()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sqlite

We are currently working on an android app using a local SQLite database.
First connection with the database to check the login was working fine, however the moment we made a second connection to get the info from the logged in user (basicly store his username - I know not the most secure thing, but besides the point - and use a WHERE) the application crashes when we enter the screen's On Create.

We tried for several hours to fix this nearly commenting each and every part of the new code, but we still get the same error.

The name of the user is 'levi'.

Error

```
06-08 15:43:48.718    2050-2050/com.example.wilmar.rentacube E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.wilmar.rentacube, PID: 2050
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wilmar.rentacube/com.example.wilmar.rentacube.Profile.Profile}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: levi (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT USERNAME, EMAIL, PHONENUMBER, BUSINESS, BIO, BRANCHE  FROM user WHERE USERNAME = levi
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

To get Data out of the database:

```
public void getUserForSession(){

        if (!database.isOpen())
            open();

        profile = new Profile();
        //This line bellow seems to cause the issues, why we do not know
        database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT USERNAME, NAME, EMAIL, PHONENUMBER, BUSINESS, BIO, BRANCHE  FROM " + DBOpenHelper.getUserTable() + " WHERE USERNAME EQUALS " + profile.logedinUser;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        String username, name, email, phonenumber, business, bio, branche;

//        username = "not found";
//        email = "not found";
//        phonenumber = "not found";
//        business = "not found";
//        bio = "not found";
//        branche = "not found";

        username = cursor.getString(0);
        name = cursor.getString(1);
        email =cursor.getString(2);
        phonenumber = cursor.getString(3);
        business = cursor.getString(4);
        bio = cursor.getString(5);
        branche = cursor.getString(6);

        if (database.isOpen())
            close();
        }
```

The class where we do the profile (the place that crashes when we enter it)

```
public class Profile extends Activity {

    ImageView contactImageImgView;
    MainActivity contacten = new MainActivity();
    public UserDao userDao;
    public String logedinUser;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        logedinUser = Login.userSession.getUsername();

        userDao.getUserForSession();

        Button editProfileButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BeditProfile);
        Button addContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AdContactButton);
        //Text ChangeProfilePictureText = (Text) findViewById(R.id.ChangeProfilePicture);

        String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
        String eMail = getIntent().getStringExtra("Mail");
        String Mobile = getIntent().getStringExtra("Mobile");
        String Adress = getIntent().getStringExtra("Adress");
        String Bio = getIntent().getStringExtra("Bio");


        contactImageImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewContactImage);
        TextView tv_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        TextView tv_Mail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Email);
        TextView tv_Mobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Mobile);
        TextView tv_Adress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Adress);
        TextView tv_Bio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Bio);

        tv_Name.setText(Name);
        tv_Mail.setText(eMail);
        tv_Mobile.setText(Mobile);
        tv_Adress.setText(Adress);
        tv_Bio.setText(Bio);

        if(Cube.fromUnit){
            editProfileButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //ChangeProfilePictureText.replaceWholeText("");
            tv_Name.setText(Cube.Name);
            tv_Mail.setText(Cube.eMail);
            tv_Mobile.setText(Cube.Mobile);
            tv_Adress.setText(Cube.Adress);
            tv_Bio.setText(Cube.Bio);
        }

        contactImageImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick (View v){  // error @ View v, cannot resolve symbol v , expected ;
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image*/");
                intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Profile Image"), 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_maps, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.menu_home) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.BeditProfile) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Profile.this, editProfile.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        if(resCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(reqCode == 1)
                contactImageImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Extra code:

```
public class UserDao {
SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;
User user;
Profile profile;
public  int count;

private static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = {

        DBOpenHelper.getUserId(),
        DBOpenHelper.getUsername(),
        DBOpenHelper.getPassword(),
        DBOpenHelper.getEmail(),
        DBOpenHelper.getPhonenumber(),
        DBOpenHelper.getBusiness(),
        DBOpenHelper.getName(),
        DBOpenHelper.getBio(),
        DBOpenHelper.getBranche(),
        DBOpenHelper.getHasstartup()
};

public UserDao(Context context){
    dbhelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbhelper.close();
}

public void open() {
    database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.i("Database", "Open");
}

public void close() {
    Log.i("Database", "Closed");
    dbhelper.close();
}

private User cursorToUser(Cursor cursor){
    if(!database.isOpen())
        open();

    try{
        User user = new User();
        user.set_AccountName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getUsername())));
        user.set_Bio(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getBio())));
        user.set_Businessname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getBusiness())));
        user.set_Email(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getEmail())));
        user.set_Password(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getPassword())));
        user.set_Phonenumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getPhonenumber())));
        user.set_Profilename(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getName())));
        user.set_hasStartup(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getHasstartup())));
        user.set_branche(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBOpenHelper.getBranche())));


        return user;

    }catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if(database.isOpen())
            close();
        return null;
    }
}

public void createUser(User user){

    if(!database.isOpen())
        open();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getUsername(), user.get_AccountName());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBio(), user.get_Bio());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBusiness(), user.get_Businessname());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getEmail(), user.get_Email());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getPassword(), user.get_Password());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getPhonenumber(), user.get_Phonenumber());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getName(), user.get_Profilename());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getHasstartup(), user.get_hasStartup());
    values.put(DBOpenHelper.getBranche(), user.get_branche());

    database.insert(DBOpenHelper.getUserTable(), null, values);

    Log.i("Database", "CREATE SUCCES");

    if(database.isOpen())
        close();

}

public User getUser(long columnId) {

    if (!database.isOpen())
        open();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBOpenHelper.getUserTable(), ALL_COLUMNS, DBOpenHelper.getUserId() + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(columnId)}, null, null, null);

    User user = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        user = cursorToUser(cursor);
    }

    cursor.close();

    if (database.isOpen())
        close();

    return user;

}

public List<User> getUsers(){

    if(!database.isOpen())
        open();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBOpenHelper.getUserTable(), ALL_COLUMNS, null, null, null, null, null);

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    user = new User();

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

            user = cursorToUser(cursor);

            users.add(user);
        }
    }

    cursor.close();

    if(database.isOpen())
        close();

    return users;

}

public void deleteUser(long id) {
    if (!database.isOpen())
        open();

    database.delete(DBOpenHelper.getUserTable(), DBOpenHelper.getUserId() + "=" + id, null);

    if (database.isOpen())
        close();
}

public String searchPass(String uname){

    if(!database.isOpen())
        open();

    database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM " + DBOpenHelper.getUserTable();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    String a,b;
    b = "not found";
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            a = cursor.getString(0);

            if(a.equals(uname)){
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    if (database.isOpen())
        close();

    return b;
}

public void getUserForSession(){

    if (!database.isOpen())
        open();

    profile = new Profile();
    //This line bellow seems to cause the issues, why we do not know (T^T)
    database = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT USERNAME, NAME, EMAIL, PHONENUMBER, BUSINESS, BIO, BRANCHE  FROM " + DBOpenHelper.getUserTable() + " WHERE USERNAME EQUALS " + profile.logedinUser;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

    String username, name, email, phonenumber, business, bio, branche;

    username = cursor.getString(0);
    name = cursor.getString(1);
    email =cursor.getString(2);
    phonenumber = cursor.getString(3);
    business = cursor.getString(4);
    bio = cursor.getString(5);
    branche = cursor.getString(6);

    if (database.isOpen())
        close();
    }
```

Where the userDao code works:

```
 String validPassword = userDao.searchPass(usernamestr);

        if(passwordstr.equals(validPassword)) {
            //String setSessionForUser = userDao.searchPass(usernamestr);

            //if (passwordstr.equals(setSessionForUser)) {
                Toast pass = Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Welcome " + usernamestr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                pass.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 10);
                pass.show();

                userSession.setUsername(usernamestr);

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            //}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`userDao` variable is `null` when you call `userDao.getUserForSession();` in `Profile` `onCreate` method.

You have to create `userDao` object instance before you can use it with:

```
userDao = new UserDao(this);
userDao.getUserForSession();
```

Comment: userDao is an object (a class) it doesn't get any values in the working piece of code we already got, i can post that if you like.

Comment: i will add the userDao class to the post.

Comment: You can add `UserDao` class to the post, but that can add some information on how you actually have to initialize `userDao` instance. It will not change the fact `userDao` is `null` when you are calling `getUserForSession` on it.

Comment: just added the userDao class.

Comment: thnx! problem is solved, got new error but we know hot to fix it!